# swift: How to call overrided init method of objective-C class from swift class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

This is Objective C method in YouTubeHelper class,

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id <YouTubeHelperDelegate>)delegate {
    self = [super init];

    self.delegate = delegate;
    [self initYoutubeService];

    return self;
}
```

I wanna call it in swift class,

```
override init() {
        self.youTubeHelper = YouTubeHelper()
        }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I've written a tutorial that teaches you to perform this translation yourself: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_initializers_and_factories

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be (if the delegate is self):

`self.youTubeHelper = YouTubeHelper(delegate:self)`

Comment: It gives error "self used before super.init call" And when I add super.init() before self.youTubeHelper = YouTubeHelper(delegate:self),i get error "self.youTbeHelper not initialize at super.init call".

Comment: Is the Swift code with init() a subclass of that YouTubeHelper Objective-C class? If not, why is it an override?